# Download .zip from shared FolderLink (LuckyCloud) with batch-skript

Tags: file, curl, download, zip

I have the following problem:

When I run the command below I just get a .zip file which is 9kb and won't open but the original file has 43.9Mb. I've already tried several variants with curl, but all without success.
I have already tried the way for HTML redirect. Unfortunately without success

If it helps, here the shred Link for Download: https://sync.luckycloud.de/d/fb56e4a8239a4c6cac7a/

```
curl https://sync.luckycloud.de/d/fb56e4a8239a4c6cac7a/files/?p=%2FValheimServer%20Buddelkiste%20Modpack%20v3.4%20-%20Standart.zip -O -J -L
```

I try the way with PowerShell too, but i get only the same 9kb file :/

```
# Source file location
$source = 'https://sync.luckycloud.de/d/fb56e4a8239a4c6cac7a/files/?p=%2FValheimServer%20Buddelkiste%20Modpack%20v3.4%20-%20Standart.zip'
# Destination to save the file
$destination = 'C:\Users\Anonymos\Downloads\Test.zip'
#Download the file
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $source -OutFile $destination
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve it with curl. However, with the PowerShell command invoke.

```
powershell -c "Invoke-WebRequest 'https://sync.luckycloud.de/d/fb56e4a8239a4c6cac7a/files/?p=%%2FValheimServer%%20Buddelkiste%%20Modpack%%20v3.4%20-%%20Standart.zip&dl=1' -OutFile '%FilePath%installdir\Test.zip'"
```

Be sure, that **every % is transform to %%** in the Link.

**"&dl=1"** is a specific ending from LuckyCLoud. Other Hoster use sometimes "&download=1"
You need this Link, to get the full file.

Comment: The curl solution wouldn't be any different than the Powershell solution.  If you are running the code inside a batch file, percent symbols need to be escaped with another percent symbol.